# Promise Chain Out of Order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I recently met a problem with promise Chain in javascript, specifically in Vue.js.
This is my code, I have a addItem function that insert an item in database. I want to have this function run it insert things in database then use getItems function to renew all the data. However, what I find out is that this function will run the things in the .then first then insert the item in the database at last. This caused my code to break. If any of you can help me that will be great!

```
  addItem: function() {
  this.$store.dispatch('addJournal',{
   journal: this.text,
   page: this.maxPage + 1, // increase the page number
    }).then(response => {
      this.text = ""; // set the input to empty
      this.getItems(); // get all the data from database
      this.setMaxPage(); // reset the max size
      this.currentPage = this.maxPage; // go to the max page
      this.option = "current";// set back to current
    }).catch(err => {
    });
},
```

this is other corresponding code

```
getItems: function() {
  this.pages = [];
  var tempArray = [];
  tempArray = this.$store.getters.feed;
  for (var index = 0; index < tempArray.length; ++index) {
  let page = {text:tempArray[index].journal, 
  pageNumber:tempArray[index].page};
  this.pages.push(page);
 }
},
```

this is the addJournal function in store.js

```
addJournal(context,journal) {
   console.log("this is for users", context.state.user.id)
   axios.post("/api/users/" + context.state.user.id + "/journals",journal).then(response => {
     return context.dispatch('getFeed');
        }).catch(err => {
    console.log("addJournal failed:",err);
  });
  context.dispatch('getFeed');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `addJournal` into something that returns a promise, so that it can be consumed with `then`:

```
addJournal(context, journal) {
  console.log("this is for users", context.state.user.id)
  context.dispatch('getFeed');
  return axios.post("/api/users/" + context.state.user.id + "/journals", journal).then(response => {
    return context.dispatch('getFeed');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("addJournal failed:", err);
  });
}
```

Not sure what `context.dispatch('getFeed');` does, but since `post`ing is asynchronous, there shouldn't be anything wrong with moving it above the `axios.post` line. `axios.post` returns a promise already, so you just need to return it.

Comment: this answer works. I would just like to add that to catch error from this promise, add `throw err` in `catch`.

Answer (score -1):

`.then()` works on promise

for `this.$store.dispatch('addJournal').then(...)` to work as expected, `addJournal` should be a promise.

Here's how

```
  addJournal(context, journal) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .post("/api/users/" + context.state.user.id + "/journals", journal)
        .then(response => {
          context.dispatch("getFeed");
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("addJournal failed:", err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: But the `axios` chain already returns a Promise - why create another?

Comment: @CertainPerformance true. This is my personal preference as I find it easier to consume mentally.

Comment: Thank you so much!